# Get matching records from associative array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array, columnsorting

I query a database in PHP which will get results like the following table. These are stored in an associative array.

[image: Data returned from query]

What I now want to be able to do is select only the records by a certain `work_type` and return the same type of `associative array`. For example `"Part Time"`. Then I want to be able to sort these records according to whatever column I decide. How would I do this?

This is as far as I got...

```
$data = $_SESSION['results']; //the database query results

foreach($data as $key => $row)
{
    if(in_array($row['work_type'], array('Part Time')))
    {
        $type[$key] = $row['work_type'];
        $date_posted[$key] = $row['created_at'];
    }
}
array_multisort($type, SORT_ASC, $date_posted, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

This doesn't work because the $data array which I send to `multi-sort` is a now different size to the ones I created.

Comment: what is `array('Part Time')`??

Comment: [array_filter](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) would make a lot more sense than a foreach loop here to filter your results so you only have records of a certain type. It would make a lot more sense to add a WHERE clause to your database query though. Again, sorting can be done with `ORDER BY`, assuming this is SQL or any of its dialects.

Comment: You may wanna check `https://datatables.net/` for table sorting.

Comment: Is it more efficient to just requery the database or to sort the array in PHP?

Comment: array('Part Time') is because in_array wont let me compare row['work_type'] to a string.

Comment: `array_multisort` isn't the best way to sort a complex array. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476. Ideally you'd probably want to sort right in the database though.

Comment: @Magearlik So change `in_array` to `strcasecmp($row['work_type'], 'Part Time') === 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I resolved this by just getting the data again from the database. Apparently this is more efficient.